# Forcing the use of 'filter_horizontal' for re-defined model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I have a model field `users`, but have modified its output, effectively overriding **unicode** :

```
from django import forms

class UserModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s, %s" % (obj.last_name, obj.first_name)
```

and...

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

class ArticleAdminModelForm(BaseAdminModelForm):

    users = UserModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = User.objects.order_by('last_name', 'first_name'))

    class Meta:
        model = get_model('articles', 'article')
        widgets = BaseAdminModelForm.Meta.widgets

        # Trying to force filter_horizontal -- but to no avail.
        widgets = {
            'users': FilteredSelectMultiple(
                verbose_name="users",
                is_stacked=True,
                attrs={
                    'class': 'filtered',
                })
        })
```

but I still lose the `filter_horizontal` widget in the admin.  It seems that its inextricably tied to model/dbfields only...  I've identified this area in django.contrib.admin.options.py (line 157)

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Get a form Field for a ManyToManyField.
    """
    # If it uses an intermediary model that isn't auto created, don't show
    # a field in admin.
    if not db_field.rel.through._meta.auto_created:
        return None
    db = kwargs.get('using')

    if db_field.name in self.raw_id_fields:
        kwargs['widget'] = widgets.ManyToManyRawIdWidget(db_field.rel, using=db)
        kwargs['help_text'] = ''
    elif db_field.name in (list(self.filter_vertical) + list(self.filter_horizontal)):
        kwargs['widget'] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(db_field.verbose_name, (db_field.name in self.filter_vertical))
```

So, how to 'force' use of the `filter_horizontal` for dbfield m2m fields that are redefined in `forms'??

Answer (score 1):

Defining the widget inside the user definition inside ArticleAdminModelForm would be the way to do it if you were using the normal ModelMultipleChoiceField. When subclassing a field, python by default does not call its superclass **init** method (but maybe there is some django magic behind), so you might need to implement the **init** method yourself as it says in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields).

```
users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                                      verbose_name='aktive_mitarbeiter',
                                      is_stacked=False
                                     )
        queryset=User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        )
```

*haven't tested if this works* ;)